# Having issues with SSLv3 handshake failed

Tags: tls, openssl, ubuntu

- I use positiveSSL from comodo.
- I have two servers

  - Simple node.js server
  - Darwin Calendar Server (caldavd)
- Both servers are running on same physical machine
- I installed certificates on server following articles.
- I got 3 intermediate certs from comodo positiveSSL

  ```
  AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt                 
  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt                      
  COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
  ```

I created a file `PositiveSSL.ca-bundle`:

```
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt  AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt  > PositiveSSL.ca-bundle
```

I installed the same file for node.js and caldavd. However, when I run

```
openssl s_client -host node.js.com -port 3443 -CAfile file
```

I get:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=example.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

But when I run against caldavd, I get

```
openssl s_client -host caldavd.com -port 8443 -CAfile file
```

I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735312184144:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
```

Then, if I remove the intermediate certs from caldav and:

```
openssl s_client -host caldavd.com -port 8443 -CAfile file
```

I get:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=example.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
Server certificate
```

Can you please explain what is happening?